# How to use keynote magic move with Connection Lines?

Tags: keynote

When I use magic move with connetion lines, they disappear and reappear in the next slide.

It seems like magic move doesn't recognize the connection lines (or can't match them), so it just redraws them, instead of leaving them there.

I'm trying to use magic move to make a nice presentation that includes connection lines. How can I make without the lines disappearing every time something moves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, according to several sources you can't do it. You would need to separate the lines (i.e. not use connection lines).

Answer (score 4):

I found that if I grouped the connection with something else (in my case, an image) then the connection doesn't fade out and in between slides.

Comment: That works. I've put the entire graph into one group. Note that a connection has to be in the same group as the objects it connects to, otherwise the connection won't work. If you group a connection line with something else while being connected, the connection is removed. (You won't see that unless the line lays above the object, or when you move the object)